# Understanding exactly when a data.table is a reference to (vs a copy of) another data.table

Tags: r, reference, copy, data.table, assignment-operator

I'm having a little trouble understanding the pass-by-reference properties of `data.table`. Some operations seem to 'break' the reference, and I'd like to understand exactly what's happening.

On creating a `data.table` from another `data.table` (via `<-`, then updating the new table by `:=`, the original table is also altered. This is expected, as per:

`?data.table::copy`
and [stackoverflow: pass-by-reference-the-operator-in-the-data-table-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030452/pass-by-reference-the-operator-in-the-data-table-package)

Here's an example:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(a=c(1,2), b=c(11,12))
print(DT)
#      a  b
# [1,] 1 11
# [2,] 2 12

newDT <- DT        # reference, not copy
newDT[1, a := 100] # modify new DT

print(DT)          # DT is modified too.
#        a  b
# [1,] 100 11
# [2,]   2 12
```

However, if I insert a non-`:=` based modification between the `<-` assignment and the `:=` lines above, `DT` is now no longer modified:

```
DT = data.table(a=c(1,2), b=c(11,12))
newDT <- DT        
newDT$b[2] <- 200  # new operation
newDT[1, a := 100]

print(DT)
#      a  b
# [1,] 1 11
# [2,] 2 12
```

So it seems that the `newDT$b[2] <- 200` line somehow 'breaks' the reference. I'd guess that this invokes a copy somehow, but I would like to understand fully how R is treating these operations, to ensure I don't introduce potential bugs in my code.

I'd very much appreciate if someone could explain this to me.

Comment: I just discovered this "feature", and it is horrifying.  It is widely advocated on the Internets to use `<-` instead of `=` for basic assignment in R (e.g. by Google: https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml#assignment).  But this means that data.table manipulation will not function the same way as data frame manipulation and is therefore far from a drop-in replacement to data frame.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Yes, it's subassignment in R using `<-` (or `=` or `->`) that makes a copy of the *whole* object. You can trace that using `tracemem(DT)` and `.Internal(inspect(DT))`, as below. The `data.table` features `:=` and `set()` assign by reference to whatever object they are passed. So if that object was previously copied (by a subassigning `<-` or an explicit `copy(DT)`) then it's the copy that gets modified by reference.

```
DT <- data.table(a = c(1, 2), b = c(11, 12)) 
newDT <- DT 

.Internal(inspect(DT))
# @0000000003B7E2A0 19 VECSXP g0c7 [OBJ,NAM(2),ATT] (len=2, tl=100)
#   @00000000040C2288 14 REALSXP g0c2 [NAM(2)] (len=2, tl=0) 1,2
#   @00000000040C2250 14 REALSXP g0c2 [NAM(2)] (len=2, tl=0) 11,12
# ATTRIB:  # ..snip..

.Internal(inspect(newDT))   # precisely the same object at this point
# @0000000003B7E2A0 19 VECSXP g0c7 [OBJ,NAM(2),ATT] (len=2, tl=100)
#   @00000000040C2288 14 REALSXP g0c2 [NAM(2)] (len=2, tl=0) 1,2
#   @00000000040C2250 14 REALSXP g0c2 [NAM(2)] (len=2, tl=0) 11,12
# ATTRIB:  # ..snip..

tracemem(newDT)
# [1] "<0x0000000003b7e2a0"

newDT$b[2] <- 200
# tracemem[0000000003B7E2A0 -> 00000000040ED948]: 
# tracemem[00000000040ED948 -> 00000000040ED830]: .Call copy $<-.data.table $<- 

.Internal(inspect(DT))
# @0000000003B7E2A0 19 VECSXP g0c7 [OBJ,NAM(2),TR,ATT] (len=2, tl=100)
#   @00000000040C2288 14 REALSXP g0c2 [NAM(2)] (len=2, tl=0) 1,2
#   @00000000040C2250 14 REALSXP g0c2 [NAM(2)] (len=2, tl=0) 11,12
# ATTRIB:  # ..snip..

.Internal(inspect(newDT))
# @0000000003D97A58 19 VECSXP g0c7 [OBJ,NAM(2),ATT] (len=2, tl=100)
#   @00000000040ED7F8 14 REALSXP g0c2 [NAM(2)] (len=2, tl=0) 1,2
#   @00000000040ED8D8 14 REALSXP g0c2 [NAM(2)] (len=2, tl=0) 11,200
# ATTRIB:  # ..snip..
```

Notice how even the `a` vector was copied (different hex value indicates new copy of vector), even though `a` wasn't changed. Even the whole of `b` was copied, rather than just changing the elements that need to be changed. That's important to avoid for large data, and why `:=` and `set()` were introduced to `data.table`.

Now, with our copied `newDT` we can modify it by reference :

```
newDT
#      a   b
# [1,] 1  11
# [2,] 2 200

newDT[2, b := 400]
#      a   b        # See FAQ 2.21 for why this prints newDT
# [1,] 1  11
# [2,] 2 400

.Internal(inspect(newDT))
# @0000000003D97A58 19 VECSXP g0c7 [OBJ,NAM(2),ATT] (len=2, tl=100)
#   @00000000040ED7F8 14 REALSXP g0c2 [NAM(2)] (len=2, tl=0) 1,2
#   @00000000040ED8D8 14 REALSXP g0c2 [NAM(2)] (len=2, tl=0) 11,400
# ATTRIB:  # ..snip ..
```

Notice that all 3 hex values (the vector of column points, and each of the 2 columns) remain unchanged. So it was truly modified by reference with no copies at all.

Or, we can modify the original `DT` by reference :

```
DT[2, b := 600]
#      a   b
# [1,] 1  11
# [2,] 2 600

.Internal(inspect(DT))
# @0000000003B7E2A0 19 VECSXP g0c7 [OBJ,NAM(2),ATT] (len=2, tl=100)
#   @00000000040C2288 14 REALSXP g0c2 [NAM(2)] (len=2, tl=0) 1,2
#   @00000000040C2250 14 REALSXP g0c2 [NAM(2)] (len=2, tl=0) 11,600
#   ATTRIB:  # ..snip..
```

Those hex values are the same as the original values we saw for `DT` above. Type `example(copy)` for more examples using `tracemem` and comparison to `data.frame`.

Btw, if you `tracemem(DT)` then `DT[2,b:=600]` you'll see one copy reported. That is a copy of the first 10 rows that the `print` method does. When wrapped with `invisible()` or when called within a function or script, the `print` method isn't called.

All this applies inside functions too; i.e., `:=` and `set()` do not copy on write, even within functions. If you need to modify a local copy, then call `x=copy(x)` at the start of the function. But, remember `data.table` is for large data (as well as faster programming advantages for small data). We deliberately don't want to copy large objects (ever). As a result we don't need to allow for the usual 3* working memory factor rule of thumb. We try to only need working memory as large as one column (i.e. a working memory factor of 1/ncol rather than 3).

Comment: When is this behavior desirable?

Comment: Interestingly, the behavior of copying the whole object does not occur for a data.frame object. In a copied data.frame, only the vector that was changed directly via `->` assignment changes memory location. The unchanged vectors maintain the memory location of the vectors of the original data.frame. The behavior of `data.table`s described here is the current behavior as of 1.12.2.

Answer (score 120):

### Just a quick sum up.

`<-` with `data.table` is just like base; i.e., no copy is taken until a subassign is done afterwards with `<-` (such as changing the column names or changing an element such as `DT[i,j]<-v`). Then it takes a copy of the whole object just like base. That's known as copy-on-write. Would be better known as copy-on-subassign, I think! It DOES NOT copy when you use the special `:=` operator, or the `set*` functions provided by `data.table`. If you have large data you probably want to use them instead. `:=` and `set*` will NOT COPY the `data.table`, EVEN WITHIN FUNCTIONS.

Given this example data :

```
DT <- data.table(a=c(1,2), b=c(11,12))
```

The following just "binds" another name `DT2` to the same data object bound currently bound to the name `DT` :

```
DT2 <- DT
```

This never copies, and never copies in base either. It just marks the data object so that R knows that two different names (`DT2` and `DT`) point to the same object. And so R will need to copy the object if either are *subassigned* to afterwards.

That's perfect for `data.table`, too. The `:=` isn't for doing that. So the following is a deliberate error as `:=` isn't for just binding object names :

```
DT2 := DT    # not what := is for, not defined, gives a nice error
```

`:=` is for *subassigning* by reference. But you don't use it like you would in base :

```
DT[3,"foo"] := newvalue    # not like this
```

you use it like this :

```
DT[3,foo:=newvalue]    # like this
```

That changed `DT` by reference. Say you add a new column `new` by reference to the data object, there is no need to do this :

```
DT <- DT[,new:=1L]
```

because the RHS already changed `DT` by reference. The extra `DT <-` is to misunderstand what `:=` does. You can write it there, but it's superfluous.

`DT` is changed by reference, by `:=`, EVEN WITHIN FUNCTIONS :

```
f <- function(X){
    X[,new2:=2L]
    return("something else")
}
f(DT)   # will change DT

DT2 <- DT
f(DT)   # will change both DT and DT2 (they're the same data object)
```

`data.table` is for large datasets, remember. If you have a 20GB `data.table` in memory then you need a way to do this. It's a very deliberate design decision of `data.table`.

Copies can be made, of course. You just need to tell data.table that you're sure you want to copy your 20GB dataset, by using the `copy()` function :

```
DT3 <- copy(DT)   # rather than DT3 <- DT
DT3[,new3:=3L]     # now, this just changes DT3 because it's a copy, not DT too.
```

To avoid copies, don't use base type assignation or update :

```
DT$new4 <- 1L                 # will make a copy so use :=
attr(DT,"sorted") <- "a"      # will make a copy use setattr()
```

If you want to be sure that you are updating by reference use `.Internal(inspect(x))` and look at the memory address values of the constituents (see Matthew Dowle's answer).

Writing `:=` in `j` like that allows you subassign by reference *by group*. You can add a new column by reference by group. So that's why `:=` is done that way inside `[...]` :

```
DT[, newcol:=mean(x), by=group]
```