# data.table 1.8.1.: "DT1 = DT2" is not the same as DT1 = copy(DT2)?

Tags: r, data.table

I've noticed some inconsistent (inconsistent to me) behaviour in data.table when using different assignment operators. I have to admit I never quite got the difference between "=" and copy(), so maybe we can shed some light here. If you use "=" or "<-" instead of copy() below, upon changing the copied data.table, the original data.table will change as well.

Please execute the following commands and you will see what I mean

```
library(data.table)
example(data.table)

DT
   x y  v
1: a 1 42
2: a 3 42
3: a 6 42
4: b 1  4
5: b 3  5
6: b 6  6
7: c 1  7
8: c 3  8
9: c 6  9

DT2 = DT
```

now i'll change the v column of DT2:

```
DT2[ ,v:=3L]
   x y  v
1: a 1  3
2: a 3  3
3: a 6  3
4: b 1  3
5: b 3  3
6: b 6  3
7: c 1  3
8: c 3  3
9: c 6  3
```

but look what happened to DT:

```
DT
   x y  v
1: a 1  3
2: a 3  3
3: a 6  3
4: b 1  3
5: b 3  3
6: b 6  3
7: c 1  3
8: c 3  3
9: c 6  3
```

it changed as well.
so: changing DT2 changed the original DT. not so if I use copy():

```
example(data.table)  # reset DT
DT3 <- copy(DT)
DT3[, v:= 3L]
   x y  v
1: a 1  3
2: a 3  3
3: a 6  3
4: b 1  3
5: b 3  3
6: b 6  3
7: c 1  3
8: c 3  3
9: c 6  3

DT
   x y  v
1: a 1 42
2: a 3 42
3: a 6 42
4: b 1  4
5: b 3  5
6: b 6  6
7: c 1  7
8: c 3  8
9: c 6  9
```

is this behaviour expected?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. This is expected behaviour, and well documented.

Since `data.table` uses references to the original object to achieve modify-in-place, it is very fast.

For this reason, if you **really** want to copy the data, you need to use `copy(DT)`

---

From the documentation for `?copy`:

> The data.table is modified by reference, and returned (invisibly) so
>   it can be used in compound statements; e.g., `setkey(DT,a)[J("foo")]`.
>   If you require a copy, take a copy first (using `DT2=copy(DT)`). `copy()`
>   may also sometimes be useful before `:=` is used to subassign to a
>   column by reference. See `?copy`.

See also this question :
[Understanding exactly when a data.table is a reference to vs a copy of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225098/understanding-exactly-when-a-data-table-is-a-reference-to-vs-a-copy-of-another)

Comment: Thanks @Andrie. I understand assignment by reference, and why to avoid copying in the first place. It just seems strange to me that `=` creates a link between the copy and the original, as if they were the same object (when that's not the case in R otherwise).

Comment: @FlorianOswald I agree - this can be a bit of a trap if one is not careful.

Comment: +10 if I could Andrie. @Florian Imagine a 20GB+ table in memory. We absolutely do not want to copy it, even once. But if you really want to, you can. It doesn't break compatibility with other packages, because it's only `:=` and the `set*` functions that assign by reference. It's one of the reasons we introduced a new operator (`:=`), rather than make `<-` work differently.

Comment: @MatthewDowle See, I paid attention when you talked at last week's London R user group meeting :-)

Comment: @Florian  Yes it is the case in R otherwise. `=` doesn't copy. It creates a link between the objects in base, too. It's `<-` and `=` inside a function that copy-on-change. If you use `=` inside a function on `data.table` it would be copied, too.

Comment: @Florian  Btw, congrats for asking the 200th question tagged `data.table`!

Comment: @MatthewDowle good stuff! that is 200 answered question for you? congrats to you rather! by the way, i don't want to keep nagging but I don't understand what you said: `=` doesn't copy? if i do `a=3`, `b=a`, `b=4`, i still get `a=3`. is that completely missing the point? has it to do with that data.table is a function (thus: an environment)?

Comment: @Florian After the `b=a` do `.Internal(inspect(a))` and `.Internal(inspect(b))`. See the same hex address? `b` is a mere pointer to `a` at that point. Then the `b=4` copies-on-change. I added a link to a more detailed answer into Andrie's answer, hope that helps.

Comment: @Florian Thanks to the R gods. The _illusion_ of pass-by-copy is one of the many great things about R. Lazy evaluation and lexical scope are also key to why we like R.