# Writings functions (procedures) for data.table objects

Tags: r, data.table

In the book *Software for Data Analysis: Programming with R*, John Chambers emphasizes that functions should generally not be written for their side effect; rather, that a function should return a value without modifying any variables in its calling environment.  Conversely, writing good script using data.table objects should specifically avoid the use of object assignment with `<-`, typically used to store the result of a function.

First, is a technical question. Imagine an R function called `proc1` that accepts a `data.table` object `x` as its argument (in addition to, maybe, other parameters). `proc1` returns NULL but modifies `x` using `:=`.  From what I understand, `proc1` calling `proc1(x=x1)` makes a copy of `x1` just because of the way that promises work.  However, as demonstrated below, the original object `x1` is still modified by `proc1`. Why/how is this?

```
> require(data.table)
> x1 <- CJ(1:2, 2:3)
> x1
   V1 V2
1:  1  2
2:  1  3
3:  2  2
4:  2  3
> proc1 <- function(x){
+ x[,y:= V1*V2]
+ NULL
+ }
> proc1(x1)
NULL
> x1
   V1 V2 y
1:  1  2 2
2:  1  3 3
3:  2  2 4
4:  2  3 6
>
```

Furthermore, it seems that using `proc1(x=x1)` isn't any slower than doing the procedure directly on x, indicating that my vague understanding of promises are wrong and that they work in a pass-by-reference sort of way:

```
> x1 <- CJ(1:2000, 1:500)
> x1[, paste0("V",3:300) := rnorm(1:nrow(x1))]
> proc1 <- function(x){
+ x[,y:= V1*V2]
+ NULL
+ }
> system.time(proc1(x1))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.00    0.02    0.02 
> x1 <- CJ(1:2000, 1:500)
> system.time(x1[,y:= V1*V2])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.03    0.00    0.03
```

So, given that passing a data.table argument to a function doesn't add time, that makes it possible to write procedures for data.table objects, incorporating both the speed of data.table and the generalizability of a function.  However, given what John Chambers said, that functions should not have side-effects, is it really "ok" to write this type of procedural programming in R? Why was he arguing that side effects are "bad"? If I'm going to ignore his advice, what sort of pitfalls should I be aware of? What can I do to write "good" data.table procedures?

Comment: Modifying an argument is not highly thought of in some circles, but in others it is not considered a side-effect (leaving that to refer to modification of things not in the parameter list).  That said, I'm curious about this behavior.  The function doesn't notice that [.data.table is modifying the argument?  Or perhaps only actual assignment triggers the creation of the local variable.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I'll add an answer but basically `data.table` deliberately departs from R's copy-on-write. `data.table` isn't copy-on-write, even within functions.  If you _really_ want to copy a 20GB data.table,  you need to place `x=copy(x)` at the start of the function, or write `x=copy(x)[,y:=V1*V2]` inside the function.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I think that's considered a side-effect in most circles.

Comment: @hadley That does not contradict what I have written.  In C code, one modified argument is considered normal activity (look at the standard library for hundreds of examples).  C++ obviates the need for such constructs, but yet, C is still used, and non-const arguments are still passed.

Comment: @matthewlundberg I don't follow your argument: jjust because C is still used does not mean that modifying is not a side effect. C is a side effect driven programming language.

Comment: @hadley Matthew is saying, iiuc, that passing something into a function to be modified by reference is slightly different to the function reaching outside its scope and modifying something it wasn't passed. The latter is definitely a side effect. In C that might be changing a global variable, in R creating or changing a variable in .GlobalEnv.  Some people would say modifying arguments explicitly passed in is safer than that, and don't use side effect to describe that, others do.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, the addition, modification, deletion of columns in `data.table`s is done by `reference`.  In a sense, it is a *good* thing because a `data.table` usually holds a lot of data, and it would be very memory and time consuming to reassign it all every time a change to it is made. On the other hand, it is a *bad* thing because it goes against the `no-side-effect` functional programming approach that R tries to promote by using `pass-by-value` by default. With no-side-effect programming, there is little to worry about when you call a function: you can rest assured that your inputs or your environment won't be affected, and you can just focus on the function's output. It's simple, hence comfortable.

Of course it is ok to disregard John Chambers's advice if you know what you are doing. About writing "good" data.tables procedures, here are a couple rules I would consider if I were you, as a way to limit complexity and the number of side-effects:

- a function should not modify more than one table, i.e., modifying that table should be the only side-effect,
- if a function modifies a table, then make that table the output of the function. Of course, you won't want to re-assign it: just run `do.something.to(table)` and not `table <- do.something.to(table)`. If instead the function had another ("real") output, then when calling `result <- do.something.to(table)`, it is easy to imagine how you may focus your attention on the output and forget that calling the function had a side effect on your table.

While "one output / no-side-effect" functions are the norm in R, the above rules allow for "one output or side-effect". If you agree that a side-effect is somehow a form of output, then you'll agree I am not bending the rules too much by loosely sticking to R's one-output functional programming style. Allowing functions to have multiple side-effects would be a little more of a stretch; not that you can't do it, but I would try to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Good advice.  I was concerned about point 2, returning the modified table, that it would spam the screen with large tables in interactive mode.  But no worries here, it doesn't print the whole thing.  Kudos to the data.table developers.

Comment: +1 for the great answer, flodel. However, could you elaborate a little bit more on why it is a bad idea to run `table <- do.something.to(table)`? I always thought that `<- data.table` doesn't make a copy (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359553/how-to-suppress-output-when-using-in-r-data-table)). Is that broken when using a function that returns a data.table?

Comment: +1 too. But I don't see why modifying more than one table is bad. When fast `insert()` is implemented, it'll be common practice (for me anyway) to insert into many different tables, like a database.  I agree with not writing `table<-`, though, for the reason you gave. It doesn't hurt, but not writing it helps highlight that `do.something.to` works via side-effects. Such functions I try and name starting with a verb. So `insert()` and `delete()` will be verb only side-effect functions.

Comment: Side-effect functions, such as `setkey`, return the data.table they've just modified by reference, so they can be used in compound syntax; e.g., `setkey(DT,x)["foo"]`.  The value isn't returned to be used with `<-` really, although it can be.  Also, if copy-on-write is needed, you can write `x <- copy(x)[,y:=a*b]` inside the function.

Answer (score 17):

The documentation could be improved (suggestions very welcome), but here is what's there at the moment.  Perhaps it should say "even within functions"?

In `?":="` :

> data.tables are not copied-on-change by :=, setkey or any of the other set* functions. See copy.
>
> DT is modified by reference and the new value is returned. If you require a copy, take a copy first (using DT2=copy(DT)). Recall that this package is for large data (of mixed column types, with multi-column keys) where updates by reference can be many orders of magnitude faster than copying the entire table.

and in `?copy` (but I realise this is muddled in with setkey) :

> The input is modified by reference, and returned (invisibly) so it can
>   be used in compound statements; e.g., setkey(DT,a)[J("foo")]. If you
>   require a copy, take a copy first (using DT2=copy(DT)). copy() may
>   also sometimes be useful before := is used to subassign to a column by
>   reference. See ?copy. Note that setattr is also in package bit. Both
>   packages merely expose R's internal setAttrib function at C level, but
>   differ in return value. bit::setattr returns NULL (invisibly) to
>   remind you the function is used for its side effect.
>   data.table::setattr returns the changed object (invisibly), for use in
>   compound statements.

where the last two sentences about `bit::setattr` relate to flodel's point 2, interestingly.

Also see these related questions :

[Understanding exactly when a data.table is a reference to (vs a copy of) another data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10225098/403310)
[Pass by reference: The := operator in the data.table package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8030452/403310)
[data.table 1.8.1.: “DT1 = DT2” is not the same as DT1 = copy(DT2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11192325/403310)

I very much like this part of your question :

> that makes it possible to write procedures for data.table objects,
>   incorporating both the speed of data.table and the generalizability of
>   a function.

Yes this is definitely one of the intentions. Consider how a database works: lots of different users/programs change by reference (insert/update/delete) one or more (large) tables in the database. That works fine in database land, and is more like the way data.table thinks. Hence the svSocket video on the homepage, and the desire for `insert` and `delete` (by reference, verb only, side-effect functions).