# Copy by-value/by-reference in a function

Tags: r, reference, return-value, data.table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writings functions (procedures) for data.table objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756178/writings-functions-procedures-for-data-table-objects)

I have a question concerning by-value/by-reference. `data.table` bring by-reference `data.table<-` and `:=`, but what about functions ?

```
DT <- data.table(a=c(1L,2L),b=c("foo","fii"));
f <- function(table){ table[,add:=1L]; }; 
f(DT); # would 0 or 1 copy of DT be performed here ?

R) DT
   a   b add
1: 1 foo   1
2: 2 fii   1
```

My understanding is that is using a function should imply a copy by value, but is it so ?
Regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13762050/1412059

Comment: Can I humbly suggest adding information about by-reference `<-` and function in the vignette. I am happy to it myself if I can access the `.tex`

Comment: @statquant Absolutely. Click to join the project in R-Forge and then you can commit changes. Might move to github if it makes it easier for people to contribute. You'd be very welcome!