# Modifying a value in a data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I'm new with data.table, and I'm having an issue with this class.  I have a table (`data1`) with 2 columns: `Couple` and `Ratio`. `Couple` is the `Key` of the data.table. I'm trying to modify a value in the table.

In the following code, `cple` is an existing value of `Couple`. When I run it, I get the results shown in the comments:

```
data1[cple]$Ratio[1]<-0 # I get more than 50 warnings and it doesn't work
data1$Ratio[1]<-0 # It works perfectly (but it's not the same as the above code)
```

The error seems to have something to do with Keys but I cannot figure out what it means.

Below is an example:

```
>data1<-data.table(Couple=c("a","a","b","b"),Ratio=1:4)
>data1
   Couple Ratio
1:      a     1
2:      a     2
3:      b     3
4:      b     4

>setkey(data1,Couple)

>data1["a"]$Ratio[1]<-2 #doesn't work warning message

WARNING:
#In `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, "a", value = list(Couple = c("a", "a" :
 # Coerced 'double' RHS to 'integer' to match the column's type; may have truncated precision. Either change the target column to 'double' first (by creating a new 'double' vector length 4 (nrows of entire table) and assign that; i.e. 'replace' column), or coerce RHS to 'integer' (e.g. 1L, NA_[real|integer]_, as.*, etc) to make your intent clear and for speed. Or, set the column type correctly up front when you create the table and stick to it, please.

>data1$Ratio[1]<-2 #works 
>data1
   Couple Ratio
1:      a     2
2:      a     2
3:      b     3
4:      b     4
```

So I can change the value when accessing the element by its indices, but not when accessing the value by its value.  How can I do this?

Comment: Hi there! Please make your post reproducible. Read the post [**how to make a great reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to do this. Thank you.

Comment: Try pasting the output from `dput( data1)` if your data.table doesn't have too many rows. (or use `dput( head( data1 ) )` ) if it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging from the first part of your question you want to actually do something like this:

```
data1[cple,Ratio:=c(0L,Ratio[-1])]
```

This does a binary search for the value of `cple` in the data.table key and works then on this subset. An integer zero is combined with the `Ratio` values except the first and the resulting vector is assigned by reference to `Ratio`.

Answer (score 10):

you shouldn't use `$` with `data.table` when you ASSIGN `data.table` is a daughter class of `data.frame` but it is much better as it can update by reference, without copies. Each time you try to assign with `$` like `data1$Ratio[1]<-2` it copies the whole table. You should look at the [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf) and especially the update `:=` operator. In your case `data1[Couple=='a',Ratio:=c(0L,Ratio[-1])] is what you want.

You might want to read this very good [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225098/understanding-exactly-when-a-data-table-is-a-reference-to-vs-a-copy-of-another/14293056#14293056) too.

Comment: @Roland, thanks, can you detail briefly the syntax of your answer ?