# Assigning values in first rows of groups in a data.table

Tags: r, grouping, data.table, variable-assignment

I'd like to assign only those values in the first row of a group in a `data.table`.

For example (simplified): my `data.table` is `DT` with the following content

```
x v  
1 1  
2 2  
2 3  
3 4  
3 5  
3 6
```

The `key` of `DT` is `x`.
I want to address every first line of a group.

This is working fine:`DT[, .SD[1], by=x]`

```
x v  
1 1  
2 2  
3 4
```

Now, I want to assign only those values of `v` to `0`.

But none of this is working:

```
DT[, .SD[1], by=x]$v <- 0  
DT[, .SD[1], by=x]$v := 0  
DT[, .SD[1], by=x, v:=0]
```

I searched the R-help from the package and any links provided but I just can't get it work.
I found notes there saying this would not work but no examples/solutions that helped me out.

I'd be very glad for any suggestions.

(I like this package very much and I don't wanna go back to a data.frame... where I got this working)

edit:

I'd like to have a result like this:

```
x v  
1 0  
2 0  
2 3  
3 0  
3 5  
3 6
```

This is not working:

```
DT[, .SD[1], by=x] <- DT[, .SD[1], by=x][, v:=0]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a little help from [Roland's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573171/modifying-a-value-in-a-data-table-in-r), it looks like you could do the following.  It simply concatenates zero with all the other grouped values of `v` except the first.

```
DT[, v := c(0L, v[-1]), by = x]   ## must have the "L" after 0, as 0L
```

which results in

```
DT
#    x v
# 1: 1 0
# 2: 2 0
# 3: 2 3
# 4: 3 0
# 5: 3 5
# 6: 3 6
```

Note:  the middle section `j` of code could also be `v := c(integer(1), v[-1])`

Answer (score 8):

Another option would be:

```
 DT[,v:={v[1]<-0L;v}, by=x]
 DT
 #  x v
 #1: 1 0
 #2: 2 0
 #3: 2 3
 #4: 3 0
 #5: 3 5
 #6: 3 6
```

Or

```
 DT[DT[, .I[1], by=x]$V1, v:=0]
 DT
 #   x v
 #1: 1 0
 #2: 2 0
 #3: 2 3
 #4: 3 0
 #5: 3 5
 #6: 3 6
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me another option! I'm still learning how to use `data.table`.