# merge-like scenario with two data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

I have two dataframes (actually data.tables).

```
set.seed(123)
dt1 <- data.table(P=rep(letters[1:3],c(4,2,3)),X=sample(9))
dt1
   P X
1: a 3
2: a 7
3: a 9
4: a 6
5: b 5
6: b 1
7: c 2
8: c 8
9: c 4
```

and:

```
dt2 <- data.table(P=rep(letters[1:5],length=10),D=c("X","Y","Z","G","F"))
dt2
    P D
 1: a X
 2: b Y
 3: c Z
 4: d G
 5: e F
 6: a X
 7: b Y
 8: c Z
 9: d G
10: e F
```

Now I want to add a new column to dt1, with column "D" of dt2 where P has the same value in dt1 and dt2. It should look like this:

```
dt_new
   P X D
1: a 3 X
2: a 7 X
3: a 9 X
4: a 6 X
5: b 5 Y
6: b 1 Y
7: c 2 Z
8: c 8 Z
9: c 4 Z
```

Comment: Please fix your syntax so your code can run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd do a `data.table join` in this manner:

```
setkey(dt1, P)
dt1[unique(dt2),nomatch=0]

   P X D
1: a 3 X
2: a 7 X
3: a 9 X
4: a 6 X
5: b 5 Y
6: b 1 Y
7: c 2 Z
8: c 8 Z
9: c 4 Z
```

Answer (score 6):

+1 to Arun's answer. To show the update-by-reference way to do this ...

Example data from question again:

```
set.seed(123)
dt1 = data.table(P=rep(letters[1:3],c(4,2,3)),X=sample(9))
dt2 = data.table(P=rep(letters[1:5],length=10),D=c("X","Y","Z","G","F"))
```

Removed dups in example data using `unique()` as Arun did :

```
dt2 = unique(dt2)  
dt2
   P D
1: a X
2: b Y
3: c Z
4: d G
5: e F
```

Now add D by reference to dt1 with data from dt2. Like a foreign key in SQL.  Admittedly this syntax isn't obvious or particularly elegant but it does avoid the copy of `dt1`. So it can be significantly faster if `dt1` is say 10GB in size.

```
setkey(dt2, P)
dt1[,D:={ .P=P           # allows us to refer to the P from dt1 on next line
          dt2[.P,D]$D}]  # since P is type character, no need to J() or .()
dt1
   P X D
1: a 3 X
2: a 7 X
3: a 9 X
4: a 6 X
5: b 5 Y
6: b 1 Y
7: c 2 Z
8: c 8 Z
9: c 4 Z
```

Or, keeping the duplicates in dt2:

```
set.seed(123)
dt1 = data.table(P=rep(letters[1:3],c(4,2,3)),X=sample(9))
dt2 = data.table(P=rep(letters[1:5],length=10),D=c("X","Y","Z","G","F"))
setkey(dt2,P)
dt2
    P D
 1: a X
 2: a X
 3: b Y
 4: b Y
 5: c Z
 6: c Z
 7: d G
 8: d G
 9: e F
10: e F
dt1[,D:={ .P=P
          dt2[.P,D,mult="first"]}]
dt1
   P X D
1: a 3 X
2: a 7 X
3: a 9 X
4: a 6 X
5: b 5 Y
6: b 1 Y
7: c 2 Z
8: c 8 Z
9: c 4 Z
```

Comment: I guess you mean the extra columns of `dt1` besides the join column are not copied this way? Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @eddi Yes, none of `dt1`'s columns are copied, join columns or otherwise. Arun's answer returns a new data.table.  The other natural by-reference way is `dt1[dt2,D:=i.D]` but I seem to remember we can't use `i.` notation in the right hand side of `:=` yet. That way needs `dt1` (the typically large table) to be keyed rather than `dt2` (the typically small lookup table). But on the other hand once `dt1` is keyed there would be many fewer rows to join from `dt2` so that would be faster.

Comment: None of the columns? Doesn't `.P=P` copy the join column?

Comment: @eddi No, no copy. `.P=P` is just a new binding of the symbol `.P` to the same object that `P` is bound to, as normal in R. The first part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14293056/403310) might help. No data.table here, just the same as base R.