# <-, [[<-, $<- and := with environments

Tags: r, data.table

I am curious to know if the behavior of data.tablea with respect to environments is inconsistent. When working with data.tables, the expectation is that assigning a new variable to a data.table does not copy data but makes a new pointer to the existing table. This does not appear to be true true when the source data.table exists in another environment.  For example,

```
> attach( new.env(), name="dt" )
> e <- as.environment("dt")
> 
> assign( "mydata", data.table( x=1:3, y=1 ), e)
> mydata
   x y
1: 1 1
2: 2 1
3: 3 1
> ls()
[1] "e"
```

If we try and assign a new name to `mydata`, we don't get the expected behavior of having a pointer to the same data.

```
mydata2 <- mydata     # also makes a _copy_
mydata2[['y']] <- 5   # change the data
identical( mydata2, mydata )  
> FALSE
```

`mydata2` does not point to (the same value) as `mydata`.  It has made a copy. This is not what I would have expected from *data.table*.  I expect data.tables to behave more as singletons in which only one copy of the data exists unless an explicit `copy` is made.

In addition, `$<-` and `[[<-` cause copies to be made on the global environment.  `$<<-` and `[[<<-` do not (as expected).  Also, `:=` does not cause a copy to be made.

Is this inconsistent with respect to *data.table*'s intent?

Is this behavior inconsistent with *data.table*?

R Version Information:

> R.version
>                  _
>   platform       x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>   arch           x86_64
>   os             linux-gnu
>   system         x86_64, linux-gnu
>   status
>   major          3
>   minor          0.1
>   year           2013
>   month          05
>   day            16
>   svn rev        62743
>   language       R
>   version.string R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
>   nickname       Good Sport

Comment: `<-` isn't any different for `data.table`. You need to use the `:=` operator and `set*` functions that `data.table` provides to do things by reference. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225098/understanding-exactly-when-a-data-table-is-a-reference-to-vs-a-copy-of-another  and  `?":="`.  Your expectations are correct so long as you use `:=` and `set*`.

Comment: Oh, I get it now.  Thanks for the clarity and link to the previous answer regarding DT behavior. I would say that the behavior is a little inconsistent/unexpected, though I recognize it a limitation that you had to work with.  Great package BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operators `<-` and `=` do *not* copy in R for all objects:

```
a = c(1:10)
.Internal(inspect(a))
#@0x000000001072aa28 13 INTSXP g0c4 [NAM(1)] (len=10, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...
b = a
.Internal(inspect(b))
#@0x000000001072aa28 13 INTSXP g0c4 [NAM(2)] (len=10, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...
```

And neither is your `mydata` copied when you do `mydata2 <- mydata` (you can check this again using the above method, or by trying smth like `mydata[, y := 5]` right after the assignment and seeing how that changes both tables).

On the other hand `[[<-` and the plethora of other assignment operators do copy for both `data.frame` and `data.table` (and that's what you see) and the way to modify `data.table` by reference is to use `:=`. None of the environment stuff above matters.