# R Data table copy and modification alters original one

Tags: r, copy, data.table

When I copy a data.table and modify the new one the original one gets altered. Is this a normal behaviour?

```
dt = data.table(zone=1:5, pc=11:15)
dtt = dt
dtt[, pc := pc*2 ]
dtt

       zone pc
    1:    1 22
    2:    2 24
    3:    3 26
    4:    4 28
    5:    5 30

dt

       zone pc
    1:    1 22
    2:    2 24
    3:    3 26
    4:    4 28
    5:    5 30
```

I have no problem when creating the new data.table more explicitely: `dtt = data.table(dt)`

Comment: I'd like to vote to close this question. You can check the details in this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225098/understanding-exactly-when-a-data-table-is-a-reference-to-vs-a-copy-of-another

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you assign a new variable to an already existing variable, R doesn't create a copy, but just points to the new variable, which is very nice as you don't want to make copies unless you absolutely need to - copy on modify.

After this, since you use the`:=` operator, which modifies *in-place* (by reference), and since at the moment, both objects are pointing to the same location, it gets reflected on both the objects.

The fix is to *explicitly copy* the `data.table` using `copy()` function and then assign by reference as follows:

```
dtt = copy(dt)     ## dt and dtt are not pointing to same locations anymore
dtt[, pc := pc*2]  ## assignment by reference doesn't affect dt
```

HTH

Comment: My problem was with R data table (I first forgot to mention it sorry). I guess it implements the same data structure as the one you point out. You are right about explicitely copying the table cf. my edit.

Comment: @Arun Anything to help is good :)