# Data table assignment operator alters variable containing original names

Tags: r, data.table, variable-assignment

The code below illustrates my issue:

```
> A <- data.table(value=1)
> A_cols <- names(A)
> A[,new_value:=2]
> A_cols
[1] "value"     "new_value"
```

Here the variable `A_cols` was indirectly modified when the `:=` modifier was used to modify the `data.table` `A`. This was unexpected for me.

I understand why this use of `:=` would [modify the value pointed to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22956185/1393860) by a `data.table` assigned via something like `B <- A`, but that isn't what's happening here. The variable `A_cols` is the result of applying a *function* to my `data.table`.

Also, this behavior appears to be inconsistent since

```
> A <- data.table(value=1)
> A_num_cols <- ncol(A)
> A[,new_value:=2]
> A_num_cols
[1] 1
```

leaves the variable `A_num_cols` unaltered.

I wondered if the code behind `names` is the culprit, but there is no information in the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/names.html) that would give a clue as to why this behavior should be expected.

Is this indeed expected, and if so, are there any explanations as to the philosophy behind this and why it seems to be applied inconsistently?

Comment: [Why does data.table update names(DT) by reference, even if I assign to another variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913417/why-does-data-table-update-namesdt-by-reference-even-if-i-assign-to-another-v)

Comment: Hi @Henrik. The link you provided fully explains what is going on here. If you post the link as an answer I can accept, or perhaps the question should be marked as duplicate? Not sure what the protocol is here. Thank you for the information :)

Comment: Hi @Rookatu Thanks for your feedback. If the linked post answers your question, there is no need for me to reiterate the answer here. I just close as a dupe and your question will serve as a signpost for future visitors. Cheers.