# Understanding data.table invalid .selfref warning

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to figuring out the data.table 'invalid .selfref' error that I am getting with the code below.

```
library(data.table) 
library(dplyr)
DT <- data.table(aa=1:100, bb=rnorm(n=100), dd=gl(2,100))
DT <- DT %.% group_by(dd, aa) %.% summarize(m=mean(bb))
DT <- DT[, ee := 3]
```

The last line throws the error. Here there is the suggestion to just write the last line as `DT$ee <- 3` but doesn't really explain why it works (and the `:=` doesn't) and being a beginner data.table user also doesn't feel like the proper data.table idiom.

It IS related to the dplyr line in there that obviously changes the DT data table. But when I change that line (and those following) into `DDT <- DT %.% group_by() ...` then I still get the selfref error from the `DT[, ee := 3]` line.

Been checking the various sources but all the info there doesn't really come down, so I am still confused.

```
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  stats     methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.2        data.table_1.9.2 ggplot2_1.0.0   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] assertthat_0.1   colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.4     grid_3.1.0      
 [5] gtable_0.1.2     MASS_7.3-31      munsell_0.4.2    parallel_3.1.0  
 [9] plyr_1.8.1       proto_0.3-10     Rcpp_0.11.2      reshape2_1.4    
[13] scales_0.2.4     stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.1.0
```

Comment: Not quite sure just how new to `data.table` you are but just to check that you know we'd do that as `DT[,mean(bb),by=aa]` and chain that into `DT[,mean(bb),by=aa][,ee:=3]` ?

Comment: @Arun: sorry, fixed sessionInfo().

 I am quite new. Started out of bare computing-time necessity with it without having the time to properly dive into it. The syntax that you give is indeed not something that automatically flows out of my brain. Given the FAQ on the similarities with SQL, I'm reading that as ... [having e = 3] instead of assigning ee to 3.

Comment: @arun I updated to 1.9.3, but when I run my original code block (at the top), I still get the warning.

In the meantime I also refound http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225098/understanding-exactly-when-a-data-table-is-a-reference-to-vs-a-copy-of-another?rq=1 that also gives explanations; need to re-read that a couple of times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just ran your code, and I see the problem. `data.table` over-allocates vector of column pointers (for efficiently adding columns by reference later on) and this warning occurs when an operation (most likely inadvertently) removes that over allocation.

Let me try to explain over-allocation using [slide 45](http://user2014.r-project.org/files/tutorial_Matt.pdf) from Matt's [useR 2014](http://user2014.r-project.org/) presentation. The (blue and yellow) boxes on the top correspond to the vector of column pointers and the arrow shows the data each pointer is pointing to.

The figure on the left depicts pictorially how adding (or `cbind`ing) a column to a `data.frame` works. `cbind`ing a column basically results in a (deep or shallow) copy resulting in a new location for the vector of column pointers (shown in yellow) and the data (which has now one more column).

The figure on the right shows the `data.table` way, where there are more than 3 blue boxes to begin with, due to over-allocation while `data.table` creation. And by using `:=`, not even a *shallow copy* is being made. The vector of column pointers that were there before stay where they are and the next unused over-allocated box is used to assign your new column.

This is about the difference and as to what *over-allocation* here means.

Now the warning tells that whatever operation you did has removed this *over-allocation* - meaning the *extra* blue boxes are gone! So, we can't add columns by reference anymore, until we *over-allocate* **again** (which is unnecessary and should be avoided, but since it's already gone, we do what's the next best thing).

My guess is that your `dplyr` syntax somehow removes this over-allocation which is caught int the next step when you use `:=` and `data.table` over-allocates once again before to add new column by reference (which'll result in a shallow copy).

If I do it the `data.table` way:

```
DT <- DT[, list(m=mean(bb)), by=list(dd,aa)]
DT[, ee := 3]
```

it works just fine.

<strike>I don't have the time to look into `dplyr` right now to verify or find out what's doing this.</strike>

#### Update: Have suggested necessary changes as a pull request [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/pull/476).

Comment: That is a mighty clear explanation. Perhaps @hadley could comment on this? From my perspective it would seem that the relatively innocuous summarize() shoudn't have that a far reaching consequence?