# Using setDT inside a function

Tags: r, data.table

I'm writing a function that, among other things, coerces the input into a data.table.

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:10)
f <- function(df){setDT(df)}
f(df)
df[, temp := 1]
```

However, the last command outputs the following warning:

> Warning message: In `[.data.table`(df, , `:=`(temp, 1)) :   Invalid
>   .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a copy of the whole
>   table so that := can  add this new column by reference. At an earlier
>   point, this data.table has been copied by R (or been created manually
>   using structure() or similar). Avoid key<-, names<- and attr<- which
>   in R currently (and oddly) may copy the whole data.table. Use set*
>   syntax instead to avoid copying: ?set, ?setnames and ?setattr. Also,
>   in R<=v3.0.2, list(DT1,DT2) copied the entire DT1 and DT2 (R's list()
>   used to copy named objects); please upgrade to R>v3.0.2 if that is
>   biting. If this message doesn't help, please report to datatable-help
>   so the root cause can be fixed.

I'm using v1.9.3 of data.table and R 3.1.1. Does it mean `df` is copied at some point? How to avoid this warning?

Edit:
The code of `setDT` actually uses NSE. So this seems to work:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:10)
f <- function(df){eval(substitute(setDT(df)),parent.frame())}
f(df1)
df1[, temp := 1]
```

It seems I can do other stuffs with df within the function `f` like

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:10)
f <- function(df){
      eval(substitute(setDT(df)),parent.frame())
      df[, temp := 1]
      }
f(df1)
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Great question! The warning message should say: *... and fixed by taking a **shallow** copy of the whole table ...*. Will fix this.

`setDT` does two things:

- set the class to `data.table` from `data.frame`/`list`
- use `alloc.col` to over-allocate columns (so that `:=` can be used directly)

And the 2nd step requires a *shallow copy*, if the input is not a `data.table` already. And this is why we *assign* the value back to the symbol in it's environment (setDT's parent frame). But the parent frame for `setDT` is your function `f()`. Therefore the `setDT(df)` within your function has gone through smoothly, but the `df` that resides in the global environment will only have it's class changed, not the over-allocation (as the shallow copy severed the link).

And in the next step, `:=` detects that and shallow copies once again to *over-allocate*.

The idea so far is to use `setDT` to convert to data.tables *before* providing it to a function. But I'd like that these cases be resolved (will take a look).

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense to ask the user to use setDT before using the function anyway, at least in my case.

Comment: Interesting.  So the way `data.table` is able to add columns by reference is by allocating a longer list and then adding the columns into the longer list?

Comment: @iShouldUseAName, it over-allocates, yes. Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24476425/559784) (and the link there) for a *slightly more* detailed exposition.