# setDT() in functions fails when using future_lapply

Tags: r, data.table, r-future

Possibly related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069219/using-setdt-inside-a-function).

`future_lapply` throws an error when using `setDT` (or `as.data.table` for that matter) is used inside a function, complaining that the object is not a data.table.

This only happens when using the

1. tweaking multisession: `plan(tweak(multisession, workers = 1))`
2. running `plan(multicore)`

Any idea what is happening?

```r
library(data.table)
library(future.apply)
#> Loading required package: future

df <- data.frame(id = 1:4)
f <- function(df, x){
  df |> setDT()
  df[, temp := x]
}

# Runs fine
lapply(1:3, function(x) f(df, x))
#> [[1]]
#>    id temp
#> 1:  1    1
#> 2:  2    1
#> 3:  3    1
#> 4:  4    1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    id temp
#> 1:  1    2
#> 2:  2    2
#> 3:  3    2
#> 4:  4    2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>    id temp
#> 1:  1    3
#> 2:  2    3
#> 3:  3    3
#> 4:  4    3

# Runs fine
plan(multisession)
future_lapply(1:3, function(x) f(df, x))
#> [[1]]
#>    id temp
#> 1:  1    1
#> 2:  2    1
#> 3:  3    1
#> 4:  4    1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    id temp
#> 1:  1    2
#> 2:  2    2
#> 3:  3    2
#> 4:  4    2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>    id temp
#> 1:  1    3
#> 2:  2    3
#> 3:  3    3
#> 4:  4    3

# Tweaking the plan: fails
plan(tweak(multisession, workers = 1))
future_lapply(1:3, function(x) f(df, x))
#> Error in `:=`(temp, x): Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").

# Trying as.data.table: fails
f2 <- function(df, x){
  dt = as.data.table(df)
  dt[, temp := x]
}
future_lapply(1:3, function(x) f2(df, x))
#> Error in `:=`(temp, x): Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").

# Multicore also fails 
# [won't print on the reprex because doesn't run on RStudio, but tested running
# the script from the terminal]
plan(multicore)
#> Warning in supportsMulticoreAndRStudio(...): [ONE-TIME WARNING] Forked
#> processing ('multicore') is not supported when running R from RStudio
#> because it is considered unstable. For more details, how to control forked
#> processing or not, and how to silence this warning in future R sessions, see ?
#> parallelly::supportsMulticore
future_lapply(1:3, function(x) f(df, x))
#> [[1]]
#>    id temp
#> 1:  1    1
#> 2:  2    1
#> 3:  3    1
#> 4:  4    1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    id temp
#> 1:  1    2
#> 2:  2    2
#> 3:  3    2
#> 4:  4    2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>    id temp
#> 1:  1    3
#> 2:  2    3
#> 3:  3    3
#> 4:  4    3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on win11, R-4.1.2, future-1.23.0, future-apply-1.8.1 (all work fine).

Comment: @r2evans seems to be related with future 1.24.0, see this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/issues/606)

Comment: Glad you found something.