# Why doesn't this data.table function modify the argument?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to get learn the `data.table` package, which seems fantastic.

One behaviour I'm unable to google my way to understanding is the following:
I want to use a function to create a variable by reference. If the data input is a `data.frame` I also want to make it a `data.table`, and this works - but the variable defined is only created if the data input is already a `data.table`. This seems strange to me, anyone knows the reason for this?

E.g. after running the `bar` function (which makes the input a `data.table` if it isn't already, and then defines a variable `bar`) on the `data.frame` X, X will be a `data.table` but the variable `bar` is not created. However, on Y (X coerced to a `data.table`), the variable `bar` *is* created. Why isn't the variable `bar` created in X?

```
library(data.table)
bar <- function(x){
    if(!"data.table" %in% class(x)) setDT(x)
    x[, bar := 1:.N]
    invisible(NULL)
}
X <- data.frame(foo = letters[1:2])
Y <- as.data.table(X)
str(X)
## 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  1 variable:
##  $ foo: chr  "a" "b"
bar(X)
str(X)
## Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
##  $ foo: chr  "a" "b"
str(Y)
## Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
##  $ foo: chr  "a" "b"
##  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
bar(Y)
str(Y)
## Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ foo: chr  "a" "b"
##  $ bar: int  1 2
##  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

I'm using R 4.2.0 and data.table 1.14.2

UPDATE: this is essentially the same question as in

[Using setDT inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069219/using-setdt-inside-a-function/)

and the answer provided there clarifies the issue. Thanks to Waldi for pointing me to this.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26072152/13513328