# Apply function to multiple data tables

Tags: r, data.table, apply, lapply

I have some data tables with the same structure and I want to make a few data transformations on them (create new variables, assign missing values etc)

This is what I've tried, without success. This codes runs ok but it does not make changes to the data tables. Any ideas?

## For a reproducible example, run this snippet of code first

```
data("mtcars")              # load data
setDT(mtcars)               # convert to data table
mtcars[gear==5, gear :=NA]  # create NA values for the purpose of my application
mtcars2 <- mtcars           # create second DT
```

## My code

```
# Create function
  computeWidth <- function(dataset){
                                    dataset$gear[is.na(dataset$gear)] <- 0 # Convert NA to 0
                                    dataset[ ,width := hp + gear]          # create new variable
                                    }

# Apply function
  lapply(list(mtcars, mtcars2), computeWidth)
```

As you can see, the function works fin, but it didn't modify the data tables. ny thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your main problem is that you are using incorrect syntax. Instead of `dataset$gear[is.na(dataset$gear)] <- 0` you should be using `dataset[is.na(gear), gear := 0]`, this way `:=` will modify your original data set *outside* of the lexical scope of `lapply` (`<-` only operates *within* the lexical scope of a certain function). Thus modifying your function to

```
computeWidth <- function(dataset){
  dataset[is.na(gear), gear := 0] # Convert NA to 0
  dataset[ ,width := hp + gear]   # create new variable
}
```

and then running

```
lapply(list(mtcars, mtcars2), computeWidth)
```

Will modify the original data sets.

As a side note, if you want to generalize this to many `data.table` objects, you could look into the `tables` function and try something as the following

```
lapply(mget(tables(silent = TRUE)$NAME), computeWidth)
```

Though it is always best to keep many objects in a single list in the first place instead of filling your global environment with many objects.

---

A very important note (suggested by @Frank), you should be aware that when using `<-` on unmodified `data.table` you are actually *not* creating a new object

```
mtcars2 <- mtcars
tracemem(mtcars)
## [1] "<00000000129264F8>"
tracemem(mtcars2)
## [1] "<00000000129264F8>"
```

Thus, by only modifying `mtcars` you will also modify `mtcars2`. Instead, the correct practice is to use `copy` as in

```
mtcars2 <- copy(mtcars)
tracemem(mtcars)
## [1] "<00000000129264F8>"
tracemem(mtcars2)
## [1] "<000000001315F6B8>"
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225098/understanding-exactly-when-a-data-table-is-a-reference-to-vs-a-copy-of-another) for further details.