# update by reference of data.table fails inside a function if the data.table was loaded from file

Tags: r, data.table

I seem to have found a situation where the update by reference of data.table does not work as expected and described in [Understanding exactly when a data.table is a reference to (vs a copy of) another data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10225098/5644988).

If you load a data.table from a Rdata-file and do an update by reference via `:=` the data.table is copied implicitly (i.e. it's memory-address is changed). That works as long as you do the update in the same environment.

But, if you do the update inside a function (e.g. f(dt)), the data.table `dt` is not changed outside the function in the calling environment, because it was copied inside the function.

Here is a little example

```
# function definition
f1 <- function(dt,dtj){
    dt[,c("C","D"):=(dt[dt.j,nomatch=0][,list(C,D)])]
}


# create, save, delete and then load from file
dt <- data.table(A=c("A","A","B"),B=1:3,key=c("A"))
dt.j <- data.table(A=c("A","B","C"),C=5:7,D=c("a","a","b"))
save(dt,file="~/test.Rdata")
rm(dt)
load(file="~/test.Rdata")
address(dt)
f1(dt,dt.j)
address(dt)
dt
```

The address of dt stays the same as does the data.table.

There is nothing wrong with the code of the function. If I omit the function and just do the update, it works, but it changes the address of the data.table

```
address(dt)
dt[,c("C","D"):=(dt[dt.j,nomatch=0][,list(C,D)])]
address(dt)
dt
```

I can cope with this by copying the data.table after loading.

**What I'd like to know is if there are other situations apart from the above mentioned, where data.table shows this behavior.**

Here's the information about R (i could also replicate this behavior on a windows machine)

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Generic 22 (Generic)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8      LC_NUMERIC=C              LC_TIME=de_DE.utf8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MONETARY=de_DE.utf8    LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8  
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_DE.utf8       LC_NAME=C                 LC_ADDRESS=C             
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C            LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.utf8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C      

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.2  chron_2.3-47
```

Comment: I don't get what you're saying. When I run your 'little example' code, the `address` calls return the same value... (R 3.2.2, data.table 1.9.7, win 10)

Comment: @frank The second part of example is problematic, so not the copy-paste part. @Thomas after `load` function you can use `alloc.col(dt)`.

Comment: @frank you're right, the address hasn't changed, but neither has the data.table itself. But it should have done so because of an update by reference inside the function.

Comment: But if I skip the function (second example) and do the update by reference directly, the address changes and the data.table gets updated (i.e. the result is correct, I can access the result via `dt`). The change of address happens in the function, too. But because it happens inside the scope of the function, it's not visible outside the function in the calling environment.

Comment: @jangorecki thanks for your hint, that my problem was answered and explained already by another post (I should have searched more thoroughly beforehand). It helped me a lot understanding the reason for this behaviour of data.table.