# Getting maximum value in a row in R

Tags: r, max, data.table

I have a data table with the structure as given below:

```
structure(list(GVKEY1 = c(2721, 113609, 62634, NA, 62599, 15855, 
15855, NA, NA, NA), GVKEY2 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), GVKEY3 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), GVKEY4 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), GVKEY5 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
)), .Names = c("GVKEY1", "GVKEY2", "GVKEY3", "GVKEY4", "GVKEY5"
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

I want to create a new column which is the maximum value of all the five columns. Notice that the data has a lot of NAs.

I wrote the following line

```
patent <- patent[, GVKEY := lapply(.SD, max, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = c('GVKEY1', 'GVKEY2', 'GVKEY3', 'GVKEY4', 'GVKEY5')]
```

I get the following output.

> Warning messages:
>   1: In `[.data.table`(patent, , `:=`(GVKEY, lapply(.SD, max, na.rm = TRUE)),  :
>     Supplied 5 items to be assigned to 3280338 items of column 'GVKEY' (recycled leaving remainder of 3 items).
>   2: In `[.data.table`(patent, , `:=`(GVKEY, lapply(.SD, max, na.rm = TRUE)),  :
>     Coerced 'list' RHS to 'double' to match the column's type. Either change the target column to 'list' first (by creating a new 'list' vector length 3280338 (nrows of entire table) and assign that; i.e. 'replace' column), or coerce RHS to 'double' (e.g. 1L, NA_[real|integer]_, as.*, etc) to make your intent clear and for speed. Or, set the column type correctly up front when you create the table and stick to it, please.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. It would be great if someone can help me.

Comment: One issue: you are using the `:=` assignment operator, so you should not be using `<-` as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the vectorized `pmax` function combined with `do.call` in order to avoid by row operation. This is uses the fact that `data.table` and `data.frame` are both lists (check out `is.list(patent)`), compared to `apply` which converts the `data.table` to a matrix. Also, as mentioned in the comments, the `:=` updates *by reference* so please don't use it combined with the `<-` operator

```
patent[, GVKEY := do.call(pmax, c(na.rm = TRUE, .SD))]
```

Comment: very nice. I always forget about `pmax`, and I use `max( )` quite a lot

Comment: Can you please explain, how to write this function if I don't want to use all the five columns to calculate max. Let say max of GVKEY1, GVKEY2, and GVKEY3. Thanks.

Comment: Add `.SDcols = c('GVKEY1', 'GVKEY2', 'GVKEY3', 'GVKEY4', 'GVKEY5')` like you already doing. Or you can do it shortly using `.SDcols = paste0('GVKEY', 1:5)`

Answer (score 1):

A slight change for you, `apply` instead of `lapply`, and when using `:=`, you don't use the `<-` assignment operator*.

```
patent[, GVKEY := apply(.SD, 1, max, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = c('GVKEY1', 'GVKEY2', 'GVKEY3', 'GVKEY4', 'GVKEY5')]
```

*References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10226454/5977215
- [data.table reference semantics](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html)