# User defined function in R has an unexpected behavior

Tags: r, data.table

I have a problem with this function.
It gives me the modified data table I want but also changes the original one.

What I want is two different data tables. The input should remain unchanged and the modified one should give me what this exemple gives me.

```
if (!require('data.table')) {
  install.packages('data.table')
}

DT <- data.table(x=rnorm(10, 0, 3), y=rnorm(10, 2, 2))

func <- function(input) {

  data <- input

  data[x >= abs(1.5), c('trigger') := list(y)]
  data[y >= 3.5, c('trigger2') := list(x)]

  return (data)
}

DT_modif <- func(DT)
```

I don't know why I get this side effect.

Comment: This might be useful reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225098/understanding-exactly-when-a-data-table-is-a-reference-to-vs-a-copy-of-another

Comment: Thanks Heroka. Your links is useful.

Answer (score 4):

The point of `data.table` is that everything is passed by reference. That includes making a copy of a data table; in your code, both `data` and `input` are references to the *same* underlying table.

Use `copy` if you want a new, independent data table.

```
data <- copy(input)
```

Comment: indeed, I was not aware about the reference thing in data.table.