# Simpler way to ggplot by column indices

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a simpler way in `ggplot` to plot columns by their indices, as in function below?

```
plotYofX <- function(dt,x,y) {
    dt[,  lapply(.SD, function(x) {as.numeric(x)}), .SDcols = c(x,y)]
    ggplot(dt) + geom_step(aes(x=get(names(dt)[x]), y=get(names(dt)[y]))) + labs(x=names(dt)[x], y=names(dt)[y])
```

Typing every time `get(names(dt)[x]` and then also correcting axis names using `labs`  (e.g. instead of just writing `aes(x,y)`) seems quite convoluted for such a smart package as `ggplot2`...

This ggplot example is taken from discussion here: [Don't want original data.table to be modified when passed to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44661961/dont-want-original-data-table-to-be-modified-when-passed-to-a-function).

Comment: As far as I can tell you want `aes_string()` which allows you to pass strings to `aes()` instead of unquoted column names. If `x` and `y` are indices, it'd be something like `ggplot(aes_string(colnames(df)[x], colnames(df)[y]))`

Comment: `aes_string()` was deprecated in ggplot2 3.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Marius comment above:

One needs to use `aes_string()` which allows you to pass strings to `aes()` instead of unquoted column names. If x and y are indices, it'd be something like `ggplot(aes_string(colnames(df)[x], colnames(df)[y]))`

Comment: `aes_string()` was deprecated in ggplot2 3.0.0 so this works no more