# r data.table to copy or not to copy

Tags: r, data.table

I create a master data table that I extract smaller tables from and then combine them into a new table. The process goes like this

1. Create a master table from some other data. Call it `dt.master`
2. Create a copy of it and do some edits. Example script is

   ```
   dt.1 <- copy(dt.master)
   dt.1 <- dt.1[ v1 %in% "cat1".]
   ```
3. create other versions of dt.1 that are edited a bit. Here's the code where the mistake enters)

   ```
   dt.2 <- dt.3  <- dt.1
   ```
4. edit each of the new version as follows

   ```
   dt.2[, v1 := "dt.2"]
   unique(dt.2$v1)
   dt.3[, v1 := "dt.3"]
   unique(dt.2$v1)
   ```

I know (and eventually remember) that `dt.3  <- dt.1` doesn't create a new version of `dt.1`. But `unique(dt.2$v1)` returns "`dt.2`" in the code above; in subsequent code it returns "`dt.1`". I put my solution to this bad coding in the answer, but would also be interested in knowing why `unique(dt.2$v1)` returns a different answer. Here is some example code that demonstrates this

```
dt.master <- data.table(v1 = c("cat1", "cat1", "cat2", "cat","cat2" ), v2 = c(1,2,3,4,5))
dt.1 <- copy(dt.master)
dt.1 <- dt.1[v1 %in% "cat1",]
dt.2 <- dt.3  <- dt.1
dt.2[, v1 := "xxx"]
unique(dt.2$v1)
dt.3[, v1 := "yyy"]
unique(dt.3$v1)
print(dt.2)
```

`v1` in `dt.2` is supposed to be `xxx` but in the print statement, it is `yyy`.

Comment: This looks unnecessarily convoluted -- filling columns with values that are also names of tables. Also, this looks like a case where you shouldn't have difficulty providing a concrete example.

Comment: The choice of the table name is just a filler; not sure why I chose that. I'll try to provide a concrete example in a bit.

Comment: I suspect that this may be relevant: [Understanding exactly when a data.table is a reference to (vs a copy of) another data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225098/understanding-exactly-when-a-data-table-is-a-reference-to-vs-a-copy-of-another)

Comment: I had tried to read that before I constructed my example. Much of it is beyond me, but I don't see where it explains the different results for the unique ... code and the print ... code.

Comment: ... and I wrote the Q and A so that someone else who sees the same strange behavior will at least have a solution for it. Is that answer not worth an up vote?

Comment: Thanks for adding the example. To me it seems like a dupe of Henrik's link. All three table names are aliases for one table. Btw, I guess you've heard it before, but there's no reason to do `DT <- DT[, x := expr]` since the point of `:=` is to modify DT in-place.

Comment: Re DT <- DT[, x := expr] is redundant. Argh. Yes. I love this element of data.table and use DT[, x := expr] everywhere. Except it seems in constructing examples. I'll edit the example.

Answer (score 1):

To put the various explanations in one place and in language that makes sense to me...

`dt.2 <- dt.3  <- dt.1` has three pointers to a single region of memory

`dt.1[, v1 := "xxx"]` sets part of that region to `xxx`

`print(unique(dt.1$v1` displays that region and shows `xxx`

`dt.2[, v1 := "yyy"]` changes the same part of that region to `yyy`

`print(unique(dt.2$v1` displays the same region and now shows `yyy`

Now that the information in that region of memory has been changed,
`print(unique(dt.1$v1` displays `yyy` instead of `xxx`

A solution I adopted is to replace

```
dt.2 <- dt.3  <- dt.1
```

with

```
dt.2 <- copy(dt.1)
dt.3 <- copy(dt.1)
```