# Unexpected behaviour of data.table setcolorder

Tags: r, data.table

Lets say i have soome data stored as a data.table object. 
I want to create a backup of this object and resort the columns of the original object using data.tables setcolorder. 
The following happens to my backup object:

```
testdata <-  data.frame(A = 1:10, B = 2:11, C = 3:12)
setDT(testdata)
testdata_backup <-  testdata
names(testdata) # [1] "A" "B" "C"
names(testdata_backup) # [1] "A" "B" "C"
setcolorder(testdata, c("C", "B", "A"))
names(testdata) # [1] "C" "B" "A"
names(testdata_backup) # [1] "C" "B" "A"
```

Despite of not changing testdata_backup, the resorting of testdata looks to have an effect testdata_backup. I guess it has something to do with the memory-handling data.table uses?

If i create the backup object as a data.frame, it wont get changed:

```
testdata <-  data.frame(A = 1:10, B = 2:11, C = 3:12)
setDT(testdata)
testdata_backup <-  data.frame(testdata)
names(testdata) # [1] "A" "B" "C"
names(testdata_backup) # [1] "A" "B" "C"
setcolorder(testdata, c("C", "B", "A"))
names(testdata) # [1] "C" "B" "A"
names(testdata_backup) # [1] "A" "B" "C"
```

Is this intendend behaviour of setcolorder? 
Am i using the function wrong?

Comment: you will need `testdata_backup <-  copy(testdata)`. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225098/understanding-exactly-when-a-data-table-is-a-reference-to-vs-a-copy-of-another

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful information!