# Writing a function with an input that is a column of a dataframe called in the function

Tags: r, function, rstudio, lm

I'm trying to write a function that has as an input argument, a column of dataframes that are called iteratively in the function.

Example shown below: 
Writing a function called iter, which has 2 inputs:
1) the list of dataframes
2) the name of the column that both df1 and df2 contains

```
iter <- function (dflist, columnname) {
  for (df in dflist){
      df[,bla:=cut(columnname, etc)]
      lm(...data=df)
      etc
  }
}
```

E.g:
`dflist = list(df1,df2)`
 and df1 and df2 both contain a column called col1

I want to write a function such that when I type in
`iter(dflist,col1)`

I get `df[,bla:=cut(col1, etc)]`

However, whenever I run it now, it gives this error - `"object 'col1' not found.`

I've tried passing in col1 as a list and use get(columnname), but to no avail:

```
iter <- function (dflist, columnname) {
  for (df in dflist){
      df[,bla:=cut(get(columnname), etc)]
      lm(...data=df)
      etc
  }
}

iter(dflist,'col1')
```

But I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to have the unquoted columns? I find much easier to dynamically change columns having the `columname` argument as a single `character` string object. You can use `as.symbol()` –or `as.name()`– to create an object (`sym` in the function) that will later let you refer to said object as an R object –as opposed to its value, whatever is assigned to `columname`.

You can then use `eval()` in the regular `data.table` syntax to evaluate the `sym` object at its environmnet.

```
library(data.table)

dList <- list(
  mtcars,
  mtcars
)

dList <- lapply(dList, function(x) copy(as.data.table(x)))

iter <- function (dflist, columnname) {
  new_var <- paste0(columnname, "_sq") 
  sym <- as.symbol(columnname)
  for (df in dflist){
    df[,(new_var):= eval(sym)^2]
  }
}

iter(dList, "mpg")
```

Result...

```
> head(dList[[2]], 1)
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb mpg_sq
1:  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4    441
```

Keep in mind that `iter` will alter the objects inside `dList` even though you didn't specify `return` in the function. The assignment operator `:=` assigns whatever by reference. See this [Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225098/understanding-exactly-when-a-data-table-is-a-reference-to-vs-a-copy-of-another) to a more thorough explanation. If you wish to change the object inside the function "but outside" and return a list with the resulting objects, you need to use `data.table::copy` first:

```
iter <- function (dflist, columnname) {
  new_var <- paste0(columnname, "_sq")
  res <- vector("list", length(dflist))
  sym <- as.symbol(columnname)
  for (i in seq_along(res)){
    dt <- copy(dflist[[i]])
    res[[i]] <- dt[,(new_var):= eval(sym)^2]
  }
  return(res)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, yes as.symbol was what I was looking for.