# Accidental column deletion - What is the proper way of creating data.table backups and deleting data.table columns

Tags: r, data.table

When I used to remove columns, I would always do something like:

```
DT[, Tax:=NULL]
```

Sometimes to make a backup, I would do something like

```
DT2 <- DT
```

But just a second ago this happened:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- structure(list(Province = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 
3), Tax = c(2000, 3000, 1500, 3200, 2000, 1500, 4000, 2000, 2000, 
1000, 2000, 1500), year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

DT2 <- structure(list(Province = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 
3), Tax = c(2000, 3000, 1500, 3200, 2000, 1500, 4000, 2000, 2000, 
1000, 2000, 1500), year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

setDT(DT) 
setDT(DT2)
DT2 <- DT

# Removes Tax in BOTH datasets !!
DT2[, Tax:=NULL]
```

I remember something about this when starting to learn about data.table, but obviously this is not really desirable (for me at least).

What is the proper way to deal with this without accidentally deleting columns?

Comment: Since `data.table` uses referential semantics (*in-place*, not copy-on-write like most of R), then your assignment `DT2 <- DT` means that both variables point to the same data. This is one of the gotchas with "memory-efficient operations" that rely on in-place work: if you goof, you lose it. Any way that will protect you against this kind of mistake will be memory-inefficient, keeping one (or more) copies of data sitting around.

Comment: If you need `DT2` to be a different dataset, then use `DT2 <- copy(DT)`, after which `DT2[,Tax:=NULL]` will not affect `DT`.

Comment: You can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10226454/3768871

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You can also read FAQ. @r2evans please make an answer from your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Moved from comments.)*

Since `data.table` uses referential semantics (in-place, not copy-on-write like most of R), then your assignment `DT2 <- DT` means that both variables point to the same data. This is one of the gotchas with "memory-efficient operations" that rely on in-place work: if you goof, you lose it. Any way that will protect you against this kind of mistake will be memory-inefficient, keeping one (or more) copies of data sitting around.

If you need `DT2` to be a different dataset, then use

```r
DT2 <- copy(DT)
```

after which `DT2[,Tax:=NULL]` will not affect `DT`.

I find MattDowle's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10226454/3768871) to be informative/helpful here (though the question explicitly asked about `copy`, not just the behavior you mentioned).

Comment: Thank you very much. So weird that it took so long for it to go wrong.