# Running a function multiple times generates "accumulated" output

Tags: r, data.table

I defined a function `try_1` whose aim is to calculate the output according to two input data sets.

```
library(data.table)

# the function
try_1 <- function(in_a, in_b){
  in_b[, `:=`(Vb = Vb/1000)]
  tmp <- in_a
  tmp[, value := Va/in_b$Vb]   
  return(tmp)
}

dt_a <- data.table(Va = c(2, 5))
dt_b <- data.table(Vb = c(1000, 2000))

# run for the 1st time
dt <- try_1(dt_a, dt_b)

# run for the 2nd time
dt <- try_1(dt_a, dt_b)

# run for the 3rd time
dt <- try_1(dt_a, dt_b)
```

If I run the function only ***once***, the output `dt` is as expected, i.e.,

```
   Va value
1:  2   2.0
2:  5   2.5
```

However, if I run it the ***second*** time, `dt` changes! (I thought it should be the same as the first run since the sentence didn't change). The `value` is 1000 times larger.

```
   Va value
1:  2  2000
2:  5  2500
```

If I further ran the ***third*** time, `dt` changes again:

```
   Va   value
1:  2 2000000
2:  5 2500000
```

Could anyone tell me what causes this problem? Why doe different results occur under multiple runs?

Comment: I suspect it has to do with this line: `tmp <- in_a` You're making a copy of a `data.table` which I think modifies it even though this should be local.

Comment: You use `:=`, “assignment by reference.” .. you mutate your dt_b object on each run...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.table`s don't copy the data, just a reference to the data.table. `tmp[, value := Va/in_b$Vb]` therefore changes the data in `in_a`.

This is explained extensively in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10225098/73299).